# Catching ng-repeat duplicate error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in results.items track by item.id"><ul result-list-line></ul></li>
```

Sometimes I get `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed`. Basically a back-end problem, but I need to handle it in the FE.

Now, I know it's been discussed before: I can loop over the data and catch duplicate myself or I can bypass it by using `track by $index`. **I don't want to do either** – I want to catch the Angular error and handle it (display an error message, basically). How do I do that?

**Here's my version to Stepan Kasyanenko's answer below:**

```
  .factory('$exceptionHandler', [ '$injector', function ( $injector ) {
    return function (exception, cause) {
        // Preventing circular reference when using $rootScope
        var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        var msg = exception.message;


        // Still have the usual console error - extend instead of replace
        var $log = $injector.get('$log');
        $log.error.apply($log, arguments);

        //catching ngRepeat duplicates
        if ( msg.search("ngRepeat:dupes") > -1 ) {
            msg = "Duplicate entries were sent from the server"
        }

        // Not always you get a cause string, but if so you might want to add it to the message 
        if ( cause ) {
            msg += ". Cause: "+cause;
        }

        // No matter what I did, I couldn't inject any factory that uses $rootScope, so I used custom event instead
        $rootScope.$emit("angularError", msg);
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler).

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/qvob5uyb/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{
      countryName: 'United States',
      countryCode: 1
    }, {
      countryName: 'Canada',
      countryCode: 2
    }, {
      countryName: 'Bahamas',
      countryCode: 3
    }, {
      countryName: 'Chile',
      countryCode: 4
    }, {
      countryName: 'Chile',
      countryCode: 4
    }];

  })
  .factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
    return function(exception, cause) {
      alert(exception)
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <label>Country:</label>
    <div ng-repeat="country in countries track by country.countryCode">
      {{country.countryName}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

`$exceptionHandler` handle also custom error.

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{
      countryName: 'United States',
      countryCode: 1
    }, {
      countryName: 'Canada',
      countryCode: 2
    }, {
      countryName: 'Bahamas',
      countryCode: 3
    }, {
      countryName: 'Chile',
      countryCode: 4
    }, ];
    $scope.raiseError = function() {
      throw "my raiseError";
    }
    $scope.addBadElement = function() {
      $scope.countries.push({
        countryName: 'Chile',
        countryCode: 4
      });
    }
  })
  .factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
    return function(exception, cause) {
      alert(exception);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <label>Country:</label>
    <button ng-click="raiseError()">
      raise Error
    </button>
    <button ng-click="addBadElement()">
      Add Bad Country
    </button>
    <div ng-repeat="country in countries track by country.countryCode">
      {{country.countryName}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's definitely the way, thanks! After reading and playing some more I added few points:  
    1. It seems that cause variable is undefined in many cases, and specifically on ng-repeat dupes.
2.  You have to inject the $injector and get the $rootScope from it, if you want to use it. Otherwise you get a circular reference
`var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");`
3. You cannot inject factories that have the $rootScope injected, no matter what.

Comment: Also added 2 lines to get the usual console error, thus extending instead of replacing the behavior. (see at the top)